# ASP.NET C# language file doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I just started using explicit resource files. I performed these steps:

- In the root create the folder: `App_GlobalResources`
- Add two resx files: `LocalizedText.en-us.resx` and `LocalizedText.resx`
- In both files I have a value called '`InstitutionTitle`'
- In `LocalizedText.en-us.resx` the value is '`Institution`' and in the `LocalizedText.resx` the value is '`Instelling`'
- In my `.aspx` file I have the following label:

  `<asp:Label ID="lblInstitution" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, InstitutionTitle %>" />`

When I run this page, I always get the dutch version. Whether I set the language in my browser (FF and IE7) or not, I always get the dutch version. When I request the browsers' language I get `en-us` (using: `Response.Write(Request.Headers["Accept-Language"]);`).

What's the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you set the preferred language in the browser? What do your system's Regional settings indicate?

Comment: How can check the preferred language in the browser? The languages in my browers are only en-us. I have deleted everything else. The location on my system is Dutch. I checked this in control panel.

Comment: That's a pretty bad question subject, BTW. Surely you could edit it to say something about resources?

Comment: @MArtijn;
Fiddler has an alias to the localhost called ipv4-fiddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the language preferences in the browser is not enough. You have to make sure that the current thread's **Culture** and **UICulture** properties are set accordingly in ASP.NET.

You can do this either programmatically or declaratively on your page (Culture and UICulture attributes of the <%@Page %> directive).

Or you can let ASP.NET set them automatically by setting the web.config entry shown below and setting the Culture/UICulture properties of the page/masterpage to "auto".

```
// web.config:
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" ...>

// page/masterpage:
<%@ Page ... Culture="auto" UICulture="auto" %>
```

Check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) for details.

Comment: I added this line in my web.config within the configuration, system.web tag. But no success. I still see the dutch text and have no error message

Comment: try adding this to your page directive "<%@ Page ... Culture="auto" UICulture="auto" %>"

Comment: That work , thnx. When I add that to my masterpage, does that affect all the content pages? And why is the setting in my web.config not working?

Comment: Yes, when set on the masterpage, it applies to all pages which use that masterpage.

Comment: Thnx. And can you explain why the setting wasn't working in my web.config file? I have it commented out now and it is still working

Comment: It seems the web.config setting (enableClientBasedCulture) is not used. See this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

@martijn:

1. check the browsers caching settings.
   Caching should be off all the time
   when developing.
2. Install Firebug (FF) and Fiddler(IE)
   to see what's being transfered over
   the wire.

Hope this helps...

signed,

A fellow countryman

Comment: Fellow countryman :) The cach wasn't the problem. I will try point 2 now.

Comment: @norbertB: Just a side question - How does Firebug enable one to sniff out HTTP headers?

Comment: @NorbertB: How do i have to use Firebug to see what's happening? I don't know how to use it..

Comment: @NorbertB: Fiddler doesn't capture localhost :( It's captures when i surf to google, but when i go to my localhost, it doesn't.

Comment: @Cerebrus, @Martijn, use the `net` pannel: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel